# Consulta para calcular a quantidade de alunos do sexo feminino e do sexo masculino

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Nessa consulta eu usaria o `GROUP BY`?

Esse e o modelo [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sim, com *group by*. Já tentou algo? Se sim, poste na pergunta a consulta e os resultados que obteve.

Comment: Você quer a quantidade de alunos matriculados em algum curso de alguma disciplina, ou todos os alunos independentes disso? Etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traduzinho o tabela `Aluno` do seu modelo para `PL/PgSQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE Aluno
(
  idaluno BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  nome TEXT NOT NULL,
  cpf VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  rg VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
  sexo VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  data_nascimento DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Cadastrando Alunos:

```
INSERT INTO Aluno ( idaluno, nome, cpf, rg, sexo, data_nascimento ) VALUES
( 100, 'JOAO', '11122233300', '1234567', 'M', '1980-03-10' ),
( 200, 'JESUS', '99988877766', '45678', 'M', '1970-06-17' ),
( 300, 'MARIA', '44455566677', '09876', 'F', '1953-04-30' ),
( 400, 'MADALENA', '33399955511', '345677', 'F', '1965-10-23' ),
( 500, 'JOSE', '00987243643', '8181818', 'M', '1988-03-03' );
```

**Solução #1:** Com `GROUP BY` e `count()`:

```
SELECT
  sexo,
  COUNT(1)
FROM
  Aluno
GROUP BY
  sexo;
```

Saída:

```
| sexo | count |
|------|-------|
|    F |     2 |
|    M |     3 |
```

**Solução #2:** Com `sum()` e sem `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE WHEN sexo = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qtd_masculino,
   SUM(CASE WHEN sexo = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qtd_feminino,
   SUM(1) AS qtd_total
FROM
  Aluno;
```

Saída:

```
| qtd_masculino | qtd_feminino | qtd_total |
|---------------|--------------|-----------|
|             3 |            2 |         5 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/557d1/2